# Exception caught by gesture Null check operator used on a null value error for ontap

Tags: flutter

[image: problem is here]

I was expecting the quotes of an app which I'm creating when ontap it should change the value but here is is not happening.

Comment: First of all change this `Function? onTap` to `void Function() tap`. Then please include where you are attaching CustomAppBar Widget thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you can either provide a `default value` for `quoteIndex` or check if it is `null` before accessing the `sweetSayings` list.

In addition `onTap!()` could cause problems, it is better to use `onTap?.call` instead of it.

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  Function? onTap;
  int? quoteIndex;

  CustomAppBar({this.onTap, this.quoteIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap?.call,
      child: Container(
        child: quoteIndex == null
            ? const Text('Default Text')
            : Text(
                sweetSayings[quoteIndex!],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```